# "ssh root@ip_address" from powershell to Google cloud instance gives error “Permission denied (publickey)”

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, terminal

I've 2 compute engine instances of Ubuntu 18.04 running on Google Cloud Platform. Although i'm able to connect to them thru Putty's terminal from my Win10 PC, but I'm not able to connect to any of the instance using win10 powershell or bash.

I've my private key uploaded properly at c:/users/bob/.ssh/keyfilename and public key loaded at the account/project wide level (computer engine> metadata> ssh keys).

As told, using these very keys, I'm able to connect to my instance using putty terminal.

I've read many help articles on the same topic/wording, but almost all help articles just deal with keeping private key and public key at their rightful places, which I already have (otherwise putty wouldn't be working).

Comment: Edit your question with the exact command that you are using.

Comment: I'm using ssh root@the_ip_address_of_my_instance. 
I've edited my question so.

Comment: Where is powershell being used in your command? If the keypair and username are correct, this error typically means that the keypair file has incorrect file permissions.

Comment: I opened powershell on Win10 and gave the above-said command.
And since I'm able to login to the same GCP instance with the same key pair (and same username), thru Putty, the key-pair seems to be fully ok.

What permissions would be fine? What permissions should I give/check?

Comment: The keypair must be read-only for `ssh` which enforces this rule, putty does not. There are many answers to the question of keypair file permissions. For Windows, this is not so simple.

Comment: I made the keys lying in c:\users\bob\.ssh as read only in windows10. For a moment it seemed that its moving ahead without error. But it didn't. Same error.
Can you point me to one some  good resource.

Comment: What command did you run to make the file read only?

Comment: There are many answers for this problem on the Internet. Use Google Search. Example: https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open

Comment: Since you said that keypair should be 'read-only', I made those 2 local (public and private key) files 'Read-only' under windows. I thought you used windows terminology (otherwise you'd perhaps say xwr permissions).

Comment: When I said readonly, I mean SSH definition of readonly on Windows. What Windows or Linux defines is not important, it is what the application `ssh` defines that is important. Windows over-complicates this issue with its NT permission structure. SSH has gone overboard in its requirement of readonly on Windows.

Comment: Sorry. But now I changed the permissions to my private key as 444 (read only for everyone) and still, I'm only able to connect to my DO droplets (earlier also I was able to connect to DO droplets), but not to GCP instances. (same error: Permission Denied (Public Key).

Answer (score 0):

The process to connect to an instance using PowerShell is documented in [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#powershell) at this time is supported for Windows instances

To [connect to a Linux instance from a Windows](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) the way to go is Putty, if you really want this feature I suggest you to open a Feature Request with Google using the [Create new Compute Engine issue form](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product)

Comment: Ah! So in simplest words: It is not supported yet. So, I'll consider/mark this an answer (after waiting 2 more days).